# How to differenciate store token in .csv jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Need help.
Need to log in multiple users, so, I'm using CSV Data Set Config. Received dynamic authCode I'm storing in another .csv file, and as the result finaly I'm receiving token, which I also store in .csv.
While posting HTTP request I'm passing token with user data from .csv, How can I differentiate tokens, to post 1000 of request using 4 users only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:** JMeter automatically does it for you. you no need to save `authCode & token`  in the CSV files.

**Long Answer:**

1. Save the `authCode` using `Regular Expression Extractor`. name the variable as `authCode`.
2. Replace with `${authCode}` wherever `authCode` value is sent in subsequent requests.
3. Capture the token value using `Regular Expression Extractor` and store the value in a variable `token`
4. Replace with `${token}` wherever `token` value is sent in subsequent requests.

you no need to worry about the `thread/vuser`, to associate `authCode`, `token` and the corresponding `thread`. JMeter handles it for you by storing those `authCode`, `token` values for `each thread` and maintains the state.

For more specific answer, please share your Test Plan and mention what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for respond. So, not storing auth as you adviced, and as for token - decided to store with user data, cause further will pass this data to lots of HTTP request.

Comment: it can be hundreds of requests, you no need to store it in CSV. JMeter is already saving the value for you. you can replace token value wherever it is sent in subsequent requests. If we go by your approach, you are hard coding to use CSV values for that specific user only.